# What is the technology to differentiate the website desktop version layout with the mobile version layout like Flipkart.com or Amazon.com?

Tags: adaptive-design

What is the technology to differentiate the website desktop version layout with the mobile version layout like Flipkart.com or Amazon.com?

I have tried only responsive web design

@media query(max-width: 767px){

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mix of Responsive Design using CSS Media Query and Adatptive Design.
Detecting the device, for example via PHP, you can show or hide an area.